# Is collected rainwater on Shabbat nolad

Tags: halacha, shabbat, water, muktzeh, orach-chaim

According to Halacha, is rainwater collected on Shabbat nolad, and therefor muktzeh or no? On the one hand, it is something new which was collected, on the other hand it’s not “created” just changing states of matter.

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Eruvin.46a.1?lang=bi&with=Commentary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MB 338:30](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.338.30?lang=bi) says it’s not muktzah

> לרחיצה - דאין על המטר היורד שם מוקצה או נולד ויכול לשתותו או לרחוץ ממנו וה"ה אם הוא ראוי רק לשתיית בהמה